# Kafka Java Producer is not able to send message to kafka instance

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am running a kafka instance in a docker container with following docker-compose.yml file.

```
version: "3"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
    ports:
      - '2181:2181'
    environment:
     - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
  kafka:
    image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
      - '9093:9093'
    environment:
      - KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="topic_name:1:3"
      - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
     - KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS=CLIENT://:9092,EXTERNAL://:9093
     - KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CLIENT://127.0.0.1:9092,EXTERNAL://127.0.0.1:9093
     - KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=EXTERNAL
    depends_on:
       - zookeeper
```

It is running pretty much good. I tested kafka by sending data via kafkacat. no problem i am able to receive the data via kafka consumer. Please check following kafkacat commands.

```
kafkacat -P -b 127.0.0.1:9092 -t topic_name

kafkacat -C -b 127.0.0.1:9092 -t topic_name
```

However when i tried to send it by java producer code, I am not able to receive from kafkacat consumer. Please check java producer code below. I would like to hear your suggestions? Thanks in advance

```
public class DataProducer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaConfig()));
    kafkaTemplate.send("topic_name", "test");
}

public static Map<String, Object> kafkaConfig() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

    return props;
}}
```

Adding also metadata following kafkacat command output.

```
kafkacat -b 127.0.0.1:9092 -L
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: 127.0.0.1:9092/1):
1 brokers:
broker 1 at 127.0.0.1:9092 (controller)
2 topics:
 topic "topic_name" with 1 partitions:
   partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
topic "__consumer_offsets" with 50 partitions:
partition 0, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
partition 1, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
..
partition 48, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
partition 49, leader 1, replicas: 1, isrs: 1
```

Comment: is kafkacat running from your machine or from a(nother) docker container?

Comment: i am running kafkacat and java code from my computer

Comment: can you also add the output of this command? `kafkacat -b 127.0.01:9092 -L`

Comment: I added into question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Broker configuration seems to be fine since you get back the correct metadata.

I think the problem is in your code. `kafkaTemplate.send()` is an asynchronous operation and most likely your process ends before the producer manages to actually send the message. Try adding a `.get()` to that send method to force it in being synchronous.

```
kafkaTemplate.send("topic_name", "test").get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. It's strange, but change in maven dependency of *kafka-clients* version from `latest(2.6.0)` to `2.0.0` (or `up to 2.5.0`) helped me.